# aiogram.utils.exceptions.ValidationError: Token is invalid! Что то установил, и накрылись все боты. Удалял, устанавливал пайтон пайчарм, не помогло

Tags: python, aiogram, token

```
from aiogram import Bot, types, Dispatcher
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

from utils.db_api.db_gino import db

from data import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)

storage = MemoryStorage()

dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

__all__ = ['bot', 'storage', 'dp', 'db']
```

Comment: Токены, менял, ставил новые, тоже бес толку.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Proekt\Wall_e_Online\loader.py", line 8, in <module>
    bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
  File "C:\Proekt\Wall_e_Online\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 77, in __init__
    api.check_token(token)
  File "C:\Proekt\Wall_e_Online\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 75, in check_token
    raise exceptions.ValidationError('Token is invalid!')
aiogram.utils.exceptions.ValidationError: Token is invalid!

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Попробуй напрямую в `Bot(token="...")` запихнуть

Answer (score 0):

Вы токен вообще прописали ?
Попробуй в .bat файле написать "set" заглавными буквами(SET).